# Deployment of Strapi to a DigitalOcean droplet with Nginx server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean, strapi

I'm having an issue being able to access a Strapi app deployed to a DigitalOcean droplet running Ubuntu 18.04. The [docs](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/deployment/digitalocean) have been followed but then they just sort of end.

The app is [definitely](https://prnt.sc/iHGt5CAb89sR) running using `pm2` on the server. The Nginx [server block](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-5-setting-up-server-blocks-recommended) has been set up [successfully](https://cms.eminenceconstructionlv.com/) per the guide it seems. However, the end goal is to be able to view the Strapi admin dashboard from that domain, not just the placeholder HTML.

Is there some further configuration required in order for for the app to be accessable from that domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nginx server requires further configuration. Edit the file located at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/your_domain`.

The `location` object should have `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` by default. Replace this with the following:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```